# Sequelize Seeder to alter enum

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, psql

we have a Postgres DB and an enum `myApp_location` with 2 values `['east', 'west']`. we created it using the following seeder

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.addColumn('myApp', 'location', {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: ['east', 'west'],
    allowNull: true,
  }),
}
```

now we want to add a value to the enum. we can do it using a seeder with a query:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TYPE \"enum_myApp_location\" ADD VALUE 'north';");
  }
};
```

but we want to avoid using query in seeders and prefer using some of Sequelize built in `queryInterface` if possible

Is there any way to do it without writing a `sequelize.query`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole discussion about this topic: [github://sequelize/issues#7151](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7151)

... but after further searching for a solution, I came up with this:

```
// example based on the Question:

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const pgEnumDropQuery = queryInterface.queryGenerator.pgEnumDrop('myApp', 'location')
    await queryInterface.changeColumn('myApp', 'location', { type: Sequelize.STRING })
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(pgEnumDropQuery)
    await queryInterface.changeColumn('myApp', 'location', {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      values: ['east', 'west', 'north'],
      allowNull: true
    })
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const pgEnumDropQuery = queryInterface.queryGenerator.pgEnumDrop('myApp', 'location')
    await queryInterface.changeColumn('myApp', 'location', { type: Sequelize.STRING })
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(pgEnumDropQuery)
    await queryInterface.changeColumn('myApp', 'location', {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      values: ['east', 'west'],
      allowNull: true
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queryInterface.changeColumn`.

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
      await queryInterface.changeColumn('myApp', 'location', {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('east', 'west', 'north'),
        allowNull: true,
        transaction,
      });
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
      await queryInterface.changeColumn('myApp', 'location', {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('east', 'west'),
        allowNull: true,
        transaction,
      });
    });
  },
};
```

`down` function is to define how to undo those changes. In this case it will roll back the changes made by the `up` changes.